# How can I reassign the Python Launcher as the default for .py files?

Tags: python, windows

I just installed Python 2.7 alongside Python 3.3 on my Windows machine, and now `.py` and `.pyw` have been reset to open with Python 2.7 as opposed to the Python Launcher (the context menu option "Edit with IDLE" when right-clicking has also been reset to open with IDLE 2.7). How can I fix this and reassign everything (and where is the Python Launcher executable stored)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done the usual way. The .py extension is no exception.

1. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/change-the-program-that-opens-a-type-of-file
2. http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/defprogramxp.htm